# I made an animation, and I tried to export it as an FBX. Microsoft 3D Viewer can't open the file, and there is no animation data either

Tags: animation, export, error, .fbx

I tried to create a walking animation for a game I'm making in Unity. I made it, and exported it as an FBX. When I try to open the .fbx file in 3D Viewer, it shows me an error saying "Couldn't load 3D model. Try again later". Then I tried importing it to Unity, thinking it was a problem with the program. Couldn't see any animation.[image: Export settings] 
 
 Blender save: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sfl1NfiHlZ2pnowmk48QCz0FqjfKQKj3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I had to click the *Push Animation* button in the dope sheet tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)